# Что такое красная горка?

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Красная горка есть почти в каждом городе. Только в каждом городе этим термином обозначается что-то свое. Например, в Евпатории, где я жила три года, Красной горкой называли место, где во время войны было расстреляно много народа (уже не вспомню, кого именно).
А что такое изначально эта "красная горка" и, кстати, надо ли этот термин писать с большой буквы?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не берусь говорить за каждый случай подобных названий, но на память тут же приходит древнерусский народный весенний праздник Красная горка. Это день прихода весны. С приходом христианства он утратил популярность и был приурочен к какой-то дате, определяемой, исходя из дня празднования Пасхи. Сейчас, кажется, его связывают с именем апостола Фомы.

Так же вероятны ещё два варианта происхождения. Первое, как очевидно, это советское, где всё, абсолютно всё было красным: площади, флаги, и, скорее всего, горки тоже.

Кроме того, можно предположить, что название эта, либо какая-то другая горка получила в честь красной глины.

Answer (score 0):

Слово "красный" имеет значение "красивый". 
К народному православному празднику данный топоним вряд ли имеет отношение.
В советское время при переименовании городов также часто использовали корень "красн".